# Take a string and divide it to 2 numbers and an operator

Tags: java

I'm trying to do a project where the user types a simple mathematical question (like 14 + 3) and the program is going to do something (irrelevant). For that "something", I need the first number and the second number as two different integers, as well as the operator as a char. So I tried this code:

```
String str = "";
str = scan.next();
str.replaceAll(" ","");

int ans = 0;
int len = str.length();
int pos = 0;

String str1 = "";
char opr = ' ';
String str2 = "";

int i;
for (i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
{
    if (str.charAt(i) <= '9' && str.charAt(i) >= '0') 
    {
        pos = i;
        str1 = str1 + str.charAt(i);
    }
    else
        break;
}

opr = str.charAt(i);

for (int j = i + 1 ; j < len - i ; i++)
{
    if (str.charAt(i) <= '9' && str.charAt(i) >= '0') 
        str2 = str2 + str.charAt(i);
}

int n1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
int n2 = Integer.parseInt(str2);
```

I'm getting this problem: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)

Can anybody explain what is the problem with my code?
By the way, I'm quite new to java and better with c++.

Comment: Note that `str.replaceAll(" ","");` doesn't do what you think it does. It's an expression - it doesn't change the string. A string is immutable - all the operations defined on it create a new object rather than changing the original object. So you need to assign it back to `str` (`str = str.replace(...)`).

Comment: if this is a "real" task (not homework), then you should be using regular expressions

Comment: Please don't ask your college assignment/homework questions here.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher If this is a "real" task they should be using an expression parser, not regex.

Comment: @AsadChoudhary Asking about a code problem is perfectly valid, homework or not. The issues with homework are around evidence of effort and debugging.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I beg to differ. for the specified requirements, expression parser is an overkill. to implement an expression parser is quite an advanced and time consuming task. regex will suffice.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Then it's not a "real" task, and what they're doing is fine. The point is if they need an expression parser they should just use one (and multiple libraries already exist).

Comment: @DaveNewton, first of all, "real" or not is not related to the chosen solution. second, IMO, expression parser is not the one and only "real" solution. I have used Apache JEXL and ANTLR. implementing these libraries is complicated, difficult and requires much testing. maybe it is the perfect bullet proof solution for future requirments and such, but in the "real" world there are also deadlines, side tasks and other constraints of real life. and what "they" are doing is not fine. the above code is cumbersome and error prone. regular expr is fine. it is concise and easily implemented.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Arguing on the internet-no thanks. We'll agree to disagree. Expression parsers already exist-there's no need to re-implement a mini-language, although a simplistic parser can be had in a few dozen lines of code without resorting to something like ANTLR. Implementing mini-languages via regex is gross and difficult to extend cleanly. Whatever-ymmv. What would i know anyway, amirite?

Comment: @DaveNewton, if you dont want to argue on the internet - then don't answer. if you answer - you argue. calling an expression that is fixed format `operand operator operand` mini language (perhaps you meant DSL?) is gorss overstatement. it is a relatively very simple expression and a perfect fit for regex. find the right tool for the task. over-engineering is a known anti pattern.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Thanks for the lesson!

Comment: @DaveNewton, so far you only responded to my solution suggestions. perhaps you can enlighten all of us with a suggestion of your own? which already-existing Expression parser would you recommend for this task?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Please see the SO FAQ; library recommendations are off-topic (and trivially searchable anyway, including on SO). Although again, a simple one is easy to write.

Comment: @DaveNewton, fine. a simple expression parser is what OP was(is) trying to write. you're saying that for the specified requirements, OP design was correct, and all that is left is to root out the bugs. we're back to square 1 - agreeing to disagree. I think the root differences between us is what constitutes "mini-language" vs textual pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I am giving a solution for your root cause using regex .

```
    String s="3*4+5";
    String s1[]=s.split("[[+]-[*]/]");//put all the required symbols 
    System.out.println(s1[0]);//prints 3
    System.out.println(s1[1]);//prints 4
    System.out.println(s1[2]);//prints 5
```

Note: '+' and '*' are special regex symbols so i have enclosed them in '[]'.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error in this line `opr = str.charAt(i);`, because if the for-loop doesn't break, the i=len, and `str.charAt(len)` exceed the str length.

Comment: And his logic to get the operation is incorrect. It calculates wrong position and the copy paste code in the 2nd loop makes his logic wrong the twice :P

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution. This code snippet will break the string to 2 arrays, One containing the Integer numbers and the other containing the char mathematical opertaors

```
    String str = "14+58*81*95%44";
    String s1[]=str.split("(?=[/*+%])|(?<=[/*+%])");

    ArrayList<String> mathamaticalOpertaorsList=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> numbersList=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++) {
        if(i%2==1) {
            mathamaticalOpertaorsList.add(s1[i]);
        }
        else {
            numbersList.add(Integer.parseInt(s1[i]));
        }
    }

    char[] mathOpertaorschars = mathamaticalOpertaorsList.toString().toCharArray();
```